# Is there a way for someone to add an event from my app to my Google Calendar? (e.g., similar to Calendly?)

Tags: google-calendar-api, bubble.io

I am somewhat new to this, and I've been building an app on low code platform Bubble.io. I've recently been trying to learn the Google Calendar API to integrate a new function into my app.

**Here's what I'm trying to enable**: a Calendly-esque function where a user of the app can connect their Google Calender. The user can then send a url to non-users of the app to book time with the user on the user's Google Calendar.

**Here's my question**: how can someone book time on another persons calendar without making the calendar public? From what I've been researching the calendar has to be public to book without authorizaton, but Calendly manages to do this without making a calendar public.

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes time to read / respond!

Answer (score 1):

if you're still trying to solve this, yes this is possible. Two ways I know this can be done:

- Nylas, which would also allow you to integrate with Microsoft/Outlook calendars using the same API calls https://www.nylas.com/
- Google Calendar API https://developers.google.com/calendar

Both of these will require you to set up OAuth functions, and might require some custom javascript actions (but also might not). When I tried to set up Nylas using Bubble several months ago, it was not possible to create a Bubble OAuth flow using the API Connector with Nylas. Instead, I had to create a custom flow and it was quite confusing to set up, but eventually worked to do what you've described.